# How to draw over QLabel in Qt

Tags: qt

I have to create one screen in Qt in which I have to show a remote having lots of buttons in it and when user clicks some button on actual remote, corresponding button in the image get highlighted. So what I have done is, I have used `QLabel` and set the remote image as background image and then I have put small rectangular label for each button and filled them with semi transparent color and when user click button in actual remote label color changes, but by using this method lot of labels are getting used making code looking inefficient, so I was thinking of drawing on `QLabel` (which has a remote as background image) over buttons.

Can anybody suggest me, which API of Qt should I use, and how to follow up on this?

Comment: What do you mean by inefficient code?

Comment: [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/graphicsview.html), but unless your remote is really huge, plain buttons should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I believe QGraphics is the correct route for a completely custom  graphical interface, but if you want to try something that doesn't require you to change too much of your existing approach, you can do a widget with a custom paint event:

*This is written in PyQt but you can easily translate to Qt*

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class LabelButton(QtGui.QWidget):

    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, labelStr, pixStr, parent=None):
        super(LabelButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = labelStr
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap(pixStr)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(LabelButton, self).paintEvent(event)
        rect = event.rect()
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        painter.drawPixmap(rect, self.pix)

        pos = (rect.bottomLeft()+rect.bottomRight()) / 2
        pos.setY(pos.y()-10)
        painter.drawText(pos, self.label)

        painter.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        self.clicked.emit()

def handleClick():
    print "CLICK"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    widget = LabelButton("A Text Label", "myImage.png")
    widget.resize(600,400)
    widget.show()
    widget.raise_()

    widget.clicked.connect(handleClick)

    app.exec_()
```

This is a rough example. You can get more fine tuned with the drawing of the text. This widget takes a label string, and a picture path, and will paint the picture as the background, and the text as a label. You can do any number of things with this custom widget in both the paint event, and with custom signals and events.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code to Draw over Image in Label: 
 Image is loaded in Ui and the Code is as follows In paintevent

```
void ColorTab::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e){ 

ui->lbl_capture_img->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
ui->Lbl_color_tab_WG->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);

Cap_Image = QImage(ui->lbl_capture_img->pixmap()->toImage());
Lbl_Image = QImage(ui->Lbl_color_tab_WG->pixmap()->toImage());

QPainter painter_Lbl(&Lbl_Image);
QPainter painter_Cap(&Cap_Image);

QPen pen(Qt::white, 5, Qt::DotLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
painter_Lbl.setPen(pen);
painter_Cap.setPen(pen);
painter_Lbl.drawPolygon(blinkRect_Lbl);
painter_Cap.drawPolygon(blinkRect_Cap);
ui->lbl_capture_img->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Cap_Image));
ui->Lbl_color_tab_WG->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Lbl_Image));

painter_Cap.end();
painter_Lbl.end();
}
```